dotnet.yml in GitHub Actions makes DEBUG build then test on the DEBUG build, is it good to run "commit test" on DEBUG build?
Is it good to run "commit test" on DEBUG build? or should I make a yml that build and test the release build for the sake of "commit test" in Trunk-based development?
